# Connecting Vlan to Internet Access

Tags: networking, vlan

**My goal:**

A network divided into E.g. two Vlans that both have internet access but cannot talk to each other.

**My problem:**

*First try:*
Internet -> Fritzbox -> Managed Switch -> Clients
Didn't work. None except the default Vlan had Internet access.

So I thought, maybe its because the router doesn't understand Vlan tags.

*Second try:*
Internet -> Fritzbox -> TP-link router firewall -> Managed Switch -> Clients

Sadly I cant configure the Fritzbox in Brige mode, to only use it as a modem. The TP-Link router is a router behind a router, and I'm not sure if that's part of the problem. But even now with a switch and configured Vlans on both of them I cant get internet access on any Vlan except the default one (1). Yes the Trunk ports and VIDS are correctly set.

I am probably missing something very obvious but I cant get a hold of it. How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A FritzBox doesn't support VLANs. Also, there's just a single routed LAN interface - all the "LAN" ports are switched. Accordingly, you can't use a trunk port towards the FritzBox and need to use an access port with a single, untagged VLAN.

You'll need a layer-3 switch, a layer-2 one won't do.

1. Set up the VLANs and routing between them.
2. Connect the FritzBox using an access port with either VLAN or an additional, transfer VLAN.
3. Set up static routes on the FritzBox for the remote VLANs, pointing to the L3 switch's VLAN interface.
4. Configure ACLs on the L3 switch to control traffic between VLANs and towards the Internet.

Using a consumer router most often doesn't work since they commonly force you to NAT and support for multiple routed interfaces or VLANs is rare. Note that if you use trunk ports they need to be set up in *exactly* the same way on both sides.

If you cascade consumer routers, the inner hosts can always access the outer hosts, but not vice versa, due to source NAT from the inner to the outer LAN. Also, cascading routers is quite slow for LAN routing.